# How can I use the results in functions in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I want to define two functions, one inside the other, and loop it until it reaches the value I'm looking for. However, the values in the function are not accessible from outside the function, so the codes do not work properly. Can I get some help with that? Is there a way to achieve this?

```
def count_div(number):
    counter = 0
    for ite in range(1,number+1):
        if number % ite == 0:
            counter += 1
        else:
            continue
    else:
        #print(number, counter)
        return counter

def sum_of(order):
    num = 0
    for a in range(order+1):
        num = num + a  
    count_div(num)

#sum_of(7)

for o1 in range(100):
    if sum_of(o1) == 20:
        print(o1)
        break
    else:
        continue
else:
    print('can\'t reach')
```

there is my work but in for loop *sum_of* func. not give an usable result for comparison.. 
Thanks You.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What is the expected output for given input?

Comment: `sum_of` doesn't return anything, so your main program will always check `None == 20`.

Comment: @Jab, I'm actually a rookie in coding, so I intend to practice on functions. In this problem, the aim is to find the first number with 20 divisors in the additive numbers.

Comment: @Prune, Yes i realized this problem indeed, But i cant develop any solution because lack of my code knowledge, i think.

Comment: Good to know.  Keep working on it.  Please note that SO (Stack Overflow) is a good resource for a single, specific problem -- it is not a general tutorial or help site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the result of the function you call.

```
def sum_of(order):
    num = 0
    for a in range(order+1):
        num = num + a
    return count_div(num)
```

When there is no explicit return statement in a function python automatically returns `None`. Therefore the line `if sum_of(o1) == 20:` was comparing `None` to `20` every iteration.

Just FYI for the function `count_div` you can use `sum` for a more *pythonic* approach:

```
sum(not number%(n+1) for n in range(number)
```

And `sum_of` this is just adding all positive integers from 1-n. This can also be done using [this equation](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/groups/tatami/kumo/exs/sum/) `n*(n+1)//2` for sake of efficiency vs a looping method, thus making `sum_of` pretty much irrelevant.

```
def count_div(num):
    return sum(not num%(n+1) for n in range(num*(num+1)//2))
```

Then for your last loop:

```
for o1 in range(100):
    if count_div(o1) == 20:
        print(o1)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sum_of` function is not returning anything which is why your if condition will never work. Add a return on the last line in `sum_of` function:

```
return count_div(num)
```

Also you have lots of unnecessary `else:` statements which you should remove, here is an example:

```
def count_div(number):
    counter = 0
    for ite in range(1,number+1):
        if number % ite == 0:
            counter += 1

    #print(number, counter)
    return counter

def sum_of(order):
    num = 0
    for a in range(order+1):
        num = num + a  
    return count_div(num)

#sum_of(7)

for o1 in range(100):
    if sum_of(o1) == 20:
        print(o1)
        break
else:
    print('can\'t reach')
```